# What happens when the CMOS battery removed while main power is present?

Tags: motherboard

We were asked this question and my answer was "nothing happens there is no data loss" but the teacher told me that's a close answer! So what exactly happens in this case?

Comment: Removed from what, a desktop computer? Laptop? Something else? I'm pretty sure I've used a desktop before with a missing CMOS battery, it just didn't save any settings, but didn't try pulling it out & in while running though

Comment: The question wasn't specific but I think it mean remove it from a Desktop motherboard

Comment: When main power is present the cmos battery is doing nothing so pulling it does nothing, have no clue what your teacher is eluding to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Don't try this at home. It is damn easy to have the battery (usually a CR2032) drop onto the motherboard and short-circuit something. Or cause arcing across the contacts which also may do damage.

It doesn't make any difference if this is a laptop or desktop. In a desktop it is just easier to reach the battery. Most laptops require a fair bit of de-montage to get at that battery.

If the computer is running while it is removed nothing will happen, until you shutdown the computer and try to start it again.
At that point it will have forgotten it's clock and (in most cases) will have reset all Bios settings to factory default. Most computers will refuse to boot to the OS and you will have to enter Bios and correct/save the Bios settings first before you can start the computer normally again.
(And if you remove the battery when the computer is OFF same thing happens when you try to start it up.)

In some case (depending on motherboard design) the same will happen on a reboot (without doing a full shutdown), but most computers will get through a reboot fine without the battery as usually the Bios doesn't try to reload the CMOS settings on a reboot.